# Get color as a string stored in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, colors

I have this extension

```
 extension Color {
 static func hexColour(hexValue:UInt32)->Color
  {
  let red = Double((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
  let green = Double((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
  let blue = Double(hexValue & 0xFF) / 255.0
  return Color(red:red, green:green, blue:blue)
}
}
```

and the usage:

```
@State var  cstmBackground = Color.hexColour(hexValue: 0xFF0000)
```

I'm storing color as string(hexValue) in Firestore. This is what I use to get the color from Firestore:

```
    struct Spty: Identifiable{
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var spty: String
var color: String

} 

    class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{


    @Published var specialities = [Spty]()

func fetchData(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return }
        self.specialities = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Spty in
           let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let spty = data["spty"] as? String ?? ""
            let color = data["color"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return Spty(spty: spty, color: color)
        }
    }
    
}

}
```

To display different colors according to the hex value stored in Firestore, I need to connect both `color` in `SptyViewModel` and `(hexValue: xxxx)`, but didn't manage to. How to do it?

**EDIT:**

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

What appears on debug:

> 2020-12-17 15:28:02.590860-0300 MedApp[4917:50349] 6.34.0 -
> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
> 2020-12-17 15:28:02.592600-0300 MedApp[4917:50349] 6.34.0 -
> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the
> following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
> goo.gl/RfcP7r) info successful info successful info successful
> 2020-12-17 15:28:05.439911-0300 MedApp[4917:50347] 6.34.0 -
> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK
> name: app_measurement 2020-12-17 15:28:05.459475-0300
> MedApp[4917:50344] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012]
> Analytics collection enabled 2020-12-17 15:28:05.459898-0300
> MedApp[4917:50344] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220]
> Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics
> logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view
> event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag
> FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the
> Info.plist field error field error field error field error

All fields are strings

[image: image4]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean you need to connect `color` in the view model with `(hexValue: xxxx)`? Be more specific. And your questions will get better traction with properly-formatted code. The best programmers are often OCD and they won't even touch this question when they see the effort you've put into formatting your code.

Comment: hey, thank you for replying. I'll try my best to explain it, since English isn't my mother language and sometimes there's a language limitation. I store the Colors in firestore, right? Then, I need a way to get the color string, and for that I use the class `SptyViewModel`. Since the Colors stored are not real Colors, but strings, I need to convert them into a color so I can use them in `.background()`. For that, I use the `extension Color` (which uses a string as a color). My question is: how to do it?

Comment: @bsod The final result must be a ForEach with rectangles with different backgrounds (according to the color string stored in firestore)

Comment: In Firestore, you store the colors as string literals like `"0xFF0000"`, correct? Just curious, what happens when you store them as integers?

Comment: If I select "number" and write, for example, 0xFF0000, it automatically changes to string as there are letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answers given and after some researches and tests, I finally got it.

First, I stored, in Firestore, fields "r", "g" and "b", each one as number and with max value 255

Then, I added the following code in my existent `func fetchData()`:

```
struct Spty: Identifiable{
var id: String
var spty: String
var r: NSNumber
var g: NSNumber
var b: NSNumber

}

class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject{
@Published var specialities = [Spty]()
@Published var search = ""
func fetchData(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot else {return }
        self.specialities = documents.documents.compactMap { (doc) -> Spty? in
           let id = doc.documentID
            let spty = doc.get("spty") as! String
            let r = doc.get("r") as! NSNumber
            let g = doc.get("g") as! NSNumber
            let b = doc.get("b") as! NSNumber
            
            return Spty(id: id, spty: spty, r: r , g: g , b: b )
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Then, inside the `ForEach`, I used:

```
.background(Color(UIColor(red: CGFloat(truncating: spty.r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(truncating: spty.g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(truncating: spty.b) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)))
```

There was no need to have an `extension Color`

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Color {
    init?(rgb: [String: Int]) {
        if let r = rgb["r"],
           let g = rgb["g"],
           let b = rgb["b"] {
            let red = Double(r)/255
            let green = Double(g)/255
            let blue = Double(b)/255
            
            self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Spty: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let spty: String
    let color: Color?

    init(spty: String, rgbMap: [String: Int]) {
        self.spty = spty
        self.color = Color(rgb: rgbMap)
    }
}

class SptyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var specialities = [Spty]()

    func fetchData(){
        Firestore.firestore().collection("specialities").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                return
            }
            for doc in snapshot.documents {
                if let spty = doc.get("spty") as? String,
                   let color = doc.get("color") as? [String: Int] {
                    let s = Spty(spty: spty, rgbMap: color)
                    self.specialities.append(s)
                } else {
                    print("field error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all this explanation! However, how would I properly use it? Btw, in the first `if let`, I got the error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'"

Comment: Just fixed this error by deleting `if` in `if let data` and adding below it, `if let spty`. Is it correct?

Comment: After launching the app, the information related to `spty` isn't been displayed. I refer to this class with `@StateObject` and `.onAppear(){ self.sptyModel.fetchData() }`

Comment: @MateusNeves I made an edit to fix the error about conditional binding.

Comment: @MateusNeves btw, instead of using hex strings, you can just store the RGB values in Firestore as a map, like `[r: 100, g: 55, b: 255]`.

Comment: That's a great idea. Do I need to do any changes on the current code? How to apply them?

Comment: @MateusNeves have you tested your current setup yet regarding getting colors from hex strings?

Comment: Yes. I was able to launch the app, but nothing is being displayed.  I add print("any teste") right before return nil, and it appeared on debug, as there's a problem within the if conditions

Comment: @MateusNeves then you have a data issue. Check your database and make sure those fields exist with the correct spelling and type.

Comment: I just added screenshots showing the data is correct

Comment: All of them are strings

Comment: @MateusNeves I see the problem now: the string is not converted into a `UInt32`. I would recommend the RGB dictionary approach for sheer simplicity. Let me put something together for you.

Comment: @MateusNeves edit now uses RGB dictionary over hexadecimal strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226020/discussion-between-mateus-neves-and-bsod).